Identifying a Cosby Show episode quoting a Robert Frost poem
I'm trying to identify an episode of the Cosby Show, but I only remember a single scene from it.  It involves a character reciting at least the first couple lines of this poem by Robert Frost:

Whose woods are these I think I know  
  His house is in the village though;

This is a humorous scene, and the character is using "the village" to refer to Greenwich village in New York City, which is apparently where another character on the show lives.
Does anyone know what episode I'm talking about?  I vaguely remember the scene featuring Sondra's husband Elvin, but I'm not sure if Elvin was the one reciting the poem or if he was the one being referred to as living in Greenwich village.
A search of episode transcripts, if available, would be useful in identifying this episode.
